# Local storage of REST/JSON web service results in Android SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, rest

I'm developing my first android application which is basically a task manager in a professional context.
My data comes from a central server and the user can only modify the progression rate and the number of hours he worked on a particular task.
He can also search by task name/date/project/client...
I'm wondering if i need to store the tasks that i get from the server in a local database ? 
Would the application be too slow if i get the tasks at each session,put them all in a list then preform my operations on that list ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend storing the "current" list in a database as a local cache to handle the case where the user has no network connectivity or was unable to connect to your server.  You can display the last known good set of tasks and queue up any changes from them to the server when connectivity is restored, or not allow changes when using the cache.  Kind of like a read-only mode.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Yes it was helpful thanks.However i would still have to synchronize my local database with the request results wouldn't I ?

Comment: Yes.  That's why I also offered the suggestion about a read-only local cache.  At least then you'd only be getting updates from the REST/JSON and you wouldn't have to worry about conflicts.  To speed things along, thinking on my feet here, you could create a separate column to hold a hash value for any given row.  Then you just update the local copy for the rows where the hash values differ.

Comment: I could also use a flag to choose the rows to update.Thanks a lot Bill,you really helped me.

Comment: Yep.  A flag as simple as a boolean, or a date, etc.  I'd like to see your app when it's done.

Comment: Of course,i would love to have a professional opinion on it.I'll post the source code as soon as I'm done.